# Solutions for a long list of content types

Tags: 2010, content-type

We have a library with about 18 content types available when creating a new document.  I know our users will not like the long dropdown list that is rendered when clicking new document.  Are there any solutions out there to present this list in a better manner.  Im thinking maybe a popup that shows the content types in a grid view would be nice.

Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do any number of things. I've put a list of the Content Types as links on a page along with their descriptions, used a dropdown of my own creation, etc. SPServices can help here if any of this sounds useful.